# How to add filter to twig?

Tags: php, twig

I have to add a simple filter to Twig, that takes a number and puts it in the following:

```
$users = NoteModel::getNoteUser($number);
```

In this example, `$number` would simply be a number and it will output a string. I can't find how to do this anywhere, all the explanations sound like complete gibberish to me.

UPDATE, here is my custom Twig_Extension class.
How do I now load this class into `twig`?

```
namespace oxocero\getNoteUser;
class getNoteUser extends \Twig_Extension { 
    public function getFilters() { 
        return array( 
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('getNoteUser', array($this, 'getNoteUser')), ); 
    } 
    public function getNoteUser($user_id) { 
        $users = NoteModel::getNoteUser($user_id); return $users; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you check this guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html ? if you show what have you tried, we'd love to fix your code. :)

Comment: `namespace oxocero\getNoteUser;

class getNoteUser extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('getNoteUser', array($this, 'getNoteUser')),
        );
    }

    public function getNoteUser($user_id)
    {
    $users = NoteModel::getNoteUser($user_id);
    return $users;
    }
}`

Comment: Also, how do I make Twig load the extension?

Comment: If you use Symfony, you can do that as shown in the guide that is provided you in earlier comment. If you're using only Twig, please check here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#using-extensions

Comment: Now it says: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "getUserNote" filter`, how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you added your extension to Twig?

Comment: Yes, I have added the extension.